# PWA ERR_FAILED on refresh

Tags: google-chrome, web, local-storage, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I created a PWA with Blazor WebAssembly straight out from the template in the latest Visual Studio 2019. Most of the app is working great and I managed to add the app to my home screen on an Android phone.

My issue now however is that whenever I swipe down/refresh on any page I get the ERR_FAILED page, this is consistent. Always when I swipe down to refresh it gives me this error. The same error happens with an obviously valid URL (same URL was just loaded) when I press F5 in Chrome for the PWA. I get the ERR_FAILED. Any idea what is causing this? The navigation in the app works great otherwise. The app is hosted in a subapp in IIS called "wapp". I am using localStorage to store user data.

[ERR_FAILED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEhXJ.png)

Comment: Try to add more error information.

Comment: If I inspect the smartphone and do F5 in the remote Chrome window I still get the ERR_FAILED error. However if I do CTRL+F5 in the remote Chrome window it loads the page properly and is working great. Cannot understand why a simple F5 causes the ERR_FAILED error.

Comment: Have you modified the base href ?

Comment: Yes my base href is set to "/wapp/". Can the problem has something to do with the service worker? I read somewhere that this error can be caused if the cache doesnt find the page. If I navigate with the menu it navigates properly to the pages. Its only when I do a F5/Swipe down refresh I get this ERR_FAILED. Do I need to change something in the service worker if I changed the base href? Thanks!